# EasyAdmin - DELETE action, delete also a physical file

Tags: symfony5, easyadmin

I am using Symfony + EasyAdmin. I have an entity called "Images" that represents some images along with some details.

Right now, by default, when someone removes an image, EasyAdmin removes it just from DB, which makes sense.

I would like to be able to remove also the physical file, not just the record without creating a custom action.

**The question is:** Do you know If is there any method that "catches" the DELETE action so I could use it to remove the physical file?

**Like:** ImagesCrudController.php `public function deletedRow($id){//then I can use the $id here to remove the physical image}`

Thank you

Comment: You can make a Subscriber and delete the file from within it. Please refer to the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/events.html

Comment: Thank you @Flash this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution if anyone needs it. I used an ***Event Subscriber*** for ***AfterEntityDeletedEvent***

Thank you [Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9807055/flash) for the instructions.

```php
<?php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Entity\Images;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\AfterEntityDeletedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class EasyAdminSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ParameterBagInterface
     */
    private $parameterBag;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag)
    {
        $this->parameterBag = $parameterBag;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            AfterEntityDeletedEvent::class => ["deletePhysicalImage"],
        ];
    }

    public function deletePhysicalImage(AfterEntityDeletedEvent $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntityInstance();
        if (!($entity instanceof Images)) {
            return;
        }
        $imgpath =
            $this->parameterBag->get("kernel.project_dir") .
            "/public_html/" .
            $entity->getPath();
        if (file_exists($imgpath)) {
            unlink($imgpath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Symfony v6.4

You can do it using DoctrineEventListener

```php
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Images;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Attribute\AsDoctrineListener;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostRemoveEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

#[AsDoctrineListener(event: Events::postRemove, priority: 500, connection: 'default')]
class DoctrineEventListener {

    public function __construct(private LoggerInterface $logger) {}

    public function postRemove(PostRemoveEventArgs $args): void {
        if ($args->getEntity() instanceof Images) {
            $obj = $args->getObject();
            if ($obj->isDeleted() && !is_null($path = $obj->getFilePath())) {
                unlink($path);
                $this->logger->notice($msg = sprintf('postRemove: unlink " %s " .', $path));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just for Reference: The Image Entity (Only a part of my working code is here)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ImagesRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

#[ORM\Table(name: 'app__images')]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ImagesRepository::class)]
#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: "fileName", message: "FileName already taken")]
class Images {

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 255)]
    private ?string $entity = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 255)]
    private ?string $filePath = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 255)]
    private ?string $fileName = null;
    
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    protected $deletedAt;  

    public function __construct() {
        $this->entity = self::class;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEntity(): ?string {
        $e = $this->entity;
        return ($e == null) ? self::class : $e;
    }

    public function getFilePath(): ?string {
        return $this->filePath;
    }

    public function getFileName(): ?string {
        return $this->fileName;
    }

    public function setEntity(?string $entity): self {
        $this->entity = $entity;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setFilePath(?string $filePath) {
        $this->filePath = $filePath;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setFileName(?string $fileName) {
        $this->fileName = $fileName;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function setDeletedAt(?\DateTime $deletedAt = null) {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getDeletedAt() {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }
    
    public function isDeleted() {
        return null !== $this->deletedAt;
    }    

    #[ORM\PrePersist]
    #[ORM\PreUpdate]
    public function setEntityValue(): void {
        if (is_null($this->entity) && current(explode('\\', get_class($this->entity))) != 'App') {
            $this->entity = self::class;
        }
    }

    #[ORM\PrePersist]
    #[ORM\PreUpdate]
    public function setWebPathValue(): void {
        if (!is_null($this->filePath)) {
            $this->fileWebPath = substr($this->filePath, strpos($this->filePath, "/uploads") + 0);
        }
    }

    #[Assert\Callback]
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload) {
        if (is_null($this->getFileEdit())) {
            $context->buildViolation('Cannot insert an empty Image!')
                    ->atPath('fileEdit')
                    ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

To be NOTED: I also have this in Image used to upload Image.

```php
    #[Assert\Image]
    private ?UploadedFile $file = null;
    private ?string $fileEdit = null;
```

You can use this Image entity in Other Entity

```php
    #[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private ?Images $avatar = null;
    
    // Used to upload Image
    #[FZA\Image(dir: 'users', width: 150, height: 150, aspectRatio: 1, viewmode: 0)]
    private ?string $avatarImage = null;
```

Reference link: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist